# 502 error on file upload with Node

Tags: node.js, apache, express, multer

Those are the symptoms:

Whenever I try to upload a file to my node server I receive a 502 response, the response varies between:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /grimoireworks/admin/uploads/uploadimage.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 50.116.34.26 Port 80
```

and

```
Bad Gateway

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 50.116.34.26 Port 80
```

edit: just got this one now:

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 50.116.34.26 Port 80
```

When that happens all sessions are dropped.

This is my nodejs code, it uses multer to handle the file upload:

```
app.post('/admin/uploads/uploadimage',
    ajaxAdminLoggedIn,
    upload.single('image_file'),
    function(req, res) {
        console.log("start of upload");

        req.socket.setTimeout(10000);

        var supportedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'];
        var type = req.file.mimetype;//mime.lookup(req.files.image_file.path);

        console.log("before supportedTypes check");

        if (supportedTypes.indexOf(type) == -1) {
            fs.unlink(req.file.path);
            return res.send(415, 'Supported image formats: jpeg, jpg, jpe, gif, png.');
        }

        console.log("before targetPath");

        var targetPath = __dirname + '/public/images/';
        if (req.body.image_type == "wizard") {
            targetPath += 'classes/';
        } else if (req.body.image_type == "spell") {
            targetPath += 'spells/';
        } else {
            fs.unlink(req.file.path);
            return res.send(415, 'Invalid image type.');
        }

        console.log("before tempPath");

        var tempPath = req.file.path;

        console.log("before createReadStream");

        var source = fs.createReadStream(tempPath);
        var dest = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath + req.file.originalname);

        console.log(tempPath);
        console.log(targetPath + req.file.originalname);

        source.pipe(dest);

        console.log("after pipe");

        source.on('error', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(500, 'Something went wrong');
            }
        });

        source.on('end', function() {
            //delete file from temp folder
            fs.unlink(tempPath, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.send(500, 'Something went wrong');
                }

                res.redirect('back');
            }); //#end - unlink
        }); //#end - on.end
    }
);
```

**None of the logs appear in the out file.**

Although the file is correctly uploaded to the temporary folder.

This is my current ProxyPass:

```
ProxyPass /grimoireworks http://localhost:6161 timeout=10000
```

I have also tried with this to no avail:

```
ProxyPass /grimoireworks http://localhost:6161 retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=10000 keepalive=on
```

Those are the logs on the server:

```
[Sat Oct 15 11:45:44.242028 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 9163] (20014)Internal error: [client 189.35.255.189:20862] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1:6161, referer: http://50.116.34.26/grimoireworks/admin/uploads
[Sat Oct 15 11:45:44.242088 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 9163] [client 189.35.255.189:20862] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /grimoireworks/admin/uploads/uploadimage, referer: http://50.116.34.26/grimoireworks/admin/uploads
```

Could someone give me a hand? This is driving me insane...